# Google Sign in wizard not asking for adding new account or selecting existing - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-authentication

I am using google sign get Authenticated from google then form our app server

Implemented the login via google as described here 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating

When I click on google button and enter my google credential all working fine, but if I want to change the google account I am not able to do so

**If I click again on google button it doesn't ask for add other account or give me list of existing accounts**

It just get me login silently with previous used account

The steps which I followed

1. Setting client ID :Setting client ID in Info and App Delegate

[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";

2. Setting delegate : Setting delegate in sign in view controller

[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;

3. Calling Sign in : Once user click on Sign In button below is the code

   - (IBAction)googlePlusSignInAction:(id)sender {
     [GMDCircleLoader setOnView:self.view withTitle:@"" animated:YES];
     [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] sign

In];
}

4. Calling sign out: Once get profile detail form google then doing sign out form google

   // Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view

   - (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
     dismissViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     }
   - (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
     didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
      withError:(NSError *)error {
     [GMDCircleLoader hideFromView:self.view animated:YES];
     // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
     [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
     }

I am not sure where I am wrong I checked Jbong app but the behaviour of my app is different with that and not as per expectation

tried with Sign Out before too

[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Sign Out of Google After Being Authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936560/how-to-sign-out-of-google-after-being-authenticated)

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to be logged out and disconnect the user account possibly for choosing other accounts for signing in. You never seem to do that in your code in a proper place. Before signing in, you should sign out existing session and then try logging in.

**Swift**

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().disconnect()
```

**Objective-C**

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] disconnect];
```

Comment: Try before too but not working even I am sepratly testing in google demo app after sign out in demo app if sign in again it does not ask for password

Comment: @TarunSeera It should work. Where are you signing out in your app? The code you posted does not show that you're doing it.

Comment: [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];

Comment: @TarunSeera See updated answer. This should work, otherwise we might have to open an issue in the GitHub page for the framework.